# How to fold away all variables to improve code readabillity?

Tags: java, readability, folding

In some my code i have a lot of variables. So to make it more readable i want to be able to fold them away so instead of this:

```
public class BIhcsAhuStartSeq_v2 {
    int counterVal_1 =0;
    int counterVal_2 =0;
    String clear="";
    String reset= "reset";

    public void test(){
        if(counterVal_1==1){setString(clear)}
    }
}
```

I want to do something like the below example so i can fold all variables away. How can i do this?

```
public class BIhcsAhuStartSeq_v2 {

    { 
    int counterVal_1 =0;
    int counterVal_2 =0;
    String clear="";
    String reset= "reset";
    }

    //example, but i cant acces the variables in the constructor ?
    public void test(){
        if(counterVal_1==1){setString(clear)}
    }
}
```

Comment: if you declare them in that block, they'll be local variables. You can't, and you shouldn't. You should always be able to check the type of your variables.

You can use composition to group variables into one. But, seriously, if 4 variables causes you no longer to be able to read your code ... wait until you see production ready code. What you can do, is declare variables of a single type on one line.

Comment: thank you for replying. the above code was an example. i will have a look into composition! thank you!

Comment: Just a comment: if you're concerned about readability, have your IDE format the code. It will give you consistent spacing between words, proper indentation, line breaks etc.

Answer (score 0):

This has been asked several times here, on Stack Overflow.

Basically, the folding function implementation varies by IDE. For Eclipse, there was the Coffee-Bytes plugin to do custom (tagged), fold-able code blocks, but that has been abandoned.

https://code.google.com/archive/p/coffee-bytes/

Other mentions have been to use Jet Brains IDEA

https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2012/03/custom-code-folding-regions-in-intellij-idea-111/